# Filter list of lists based on last element of lists in list of lists and last list of list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am attempting to create a filter for my input list of lists to remove the lists who's last element is not an element of the last list of the list of lists

I am fairly new to haskell so it's probably just some dumb rookie mistake

```
FilterBoi xs = filter (\x -> elem (x) y) xs
                        Where x = last (x:xs)
                                     y = last xs
```

Returns error

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: 
a ~ t0 a
Expected type: [t0 a]
   Actual type: [a]
In the first argument of `last' , namely `xs'
In the expression: last xs
In an equation for `y' : y = last xs
Relevant bindings include
    y :: t0 a (bound at filter.hs:3:22)
    xs :: [a] (bound at filter.hs:1:11)
    FilterBoi :: [a] -> [a] (bound at filter.hs:1:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Please note that I'm entering this on a phone so the problem doesn't lie in how I have inputted but rather what I have inputted

Comment: A where is scoped per *function clause* not per lambda expression.

Comment: Ahhh thank you. Any advice on how I should go about achieving my objective?

Comment: Unlike `where`, `let x=e in e'` can be used inside expressions. (You don't really need it here, however.)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like

```
filterBoi :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterBoi xs = filter (\x -> elem (last x) y) xs
   where y = last xs
```

Note that `last` is dangerous, though, and will crash your program if applied to an empty list. So if `xs` is empty, or any list `x` inside `xs` is empty, this can crash.

(Incidentally, if `xs` is empty, `y` will never be evaluated, so no crash will arise. However, this is not trivial to spot, making the code harder to read.)

Assuming we want to discard empty `x`, an alternative is.

```
filterBoi :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterBoi [] = []   -- not needed, but clarifies the intent
filterBoi xs = filter (\x -> not (empty x) && elem (last x) y) xs
   where y = last xs
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. Empty lists shouldn't be a problem this is more so for preparing an input for a different function